# Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod'] not displaying variance in output

Tags: r, glmm, biostatistics

I'm running a linear mixed model with random effects on my data in R, and in the tutorial I have done online (http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial.pdf) on data set "politeness" the output is not listing the variance (see output code below). The online tutorial linked above doesn't have the ['lmerMod'] shown in the output, so I am wondering if there is something about the mod that is changing the output? But, more importantly, how do I find the variance? There are a lot of differences between my output and the original output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My output looks like this;

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: frequency ~ attitude + (1 | subject) + (1 | scenario)
Data: politeness
REML criterion at convergence: 793.4536

Random effects:
Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
scenario (Intercept) 14.80     
subject  (Intercept) 63.36   
Residual             25.42   
Number of obs: 83, groups:  scenario, 7; subject, 6

Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)  attitudepol  
  202.59       -19.69
```

The output from the online tutorial looks like this;

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML
Formula: frequency ~ attitude + (1 | subject) + (1 | scenario)
Data: politeness
AIC     BIC     logLik  deviance REMLdev
803.5   815.5   -396.7  807.1    793.5  

Random effects:
Groups   Name       Variance Std.Dev.
scenario (Intercept) 218.98     14.81   
subject  (Intercept) 4014.54    24.81   
Residual             646.02     25.41   
Number of obs: 83, groups:  scenario, 7; subject, 6

Fixed Effects:
            Estimate Std.   Error   t value
(Intercept)     202.588     26.750   7.573
attitudepol     -19.695     5.585   -3.527

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
attitudepol -0.103
```

Note, it was suggest I run the following code to extract the data;

```
summary(yourmodel)
as.data.frame(VarCorr(yourmodel))
```

But that came back with;

```
> as.data.frame(VarCorr(politeness.model))
       grp        var1 var2     vcov    sdcor
1 scenario (Intercept) <NA> 219.4532 14.81395
2  subject (Intercept) <NA> 615.5678 24.81064
3 Residual        <NA> <NA> 645.8951 25.41447
```

Which again are not the same values as listed in the original output, and the var2 is listing NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just printed the model object, not the summary of the model object. Try running summary(the_model) and you should get output to match the tutorial.

So something like:

```
politeness.model <- lmer(frequency ~ attitude + (1|subject) + (1|scenario),
                         data = politeness)

# what you probably used
politeness.model 

# what the tutorial probably used
summary(politeness.model)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @dmartin . The online tutorial said that the summary() wasn't required so I didn't even think to try it (silly me), but that's exactly what fixed it.